# xVal testing

Tags: c#, xval

Does anyone know how to generate a test for the xVal, or more the the point the DataAnnotations attributes

Here is some same code that I would like to test

[MetadataType(typeof(CategoryValidation))]
    public partial class Category : CustomValidation
    {
    }

```
public class CategoryValidation
{
    [Required]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string CostCode { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, testing it should be pretty easy.  For me, using NUnit, its like this:

```
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(RulesException))]
    public void Cannot_Save_Large_Data_In_Color()
    {

        var scheme = ColorScheme.Create();
        scheme.Color1 = "1234567890ABCDEF";
        scheme.Validate();
        Assert.Fail("Should have thrown a DataValidationException.");
    }
```

This assumes you have a validation runner for DataAnnotations already built and a way to call it.  If you don't here is a really simplistic one I use for testing (which I nicked from Steve Sanderson's blog):

```
internal static class DataAnnotationsValidationRunner
{
    public static IEnumerable<ErrorInfo> GetErrors(object instance)
    {
        return from prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
               from attribute in prop.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
               where !attribute.IsValid(prop.GetValue(instance))
               select new ErrorInfo(prop.Name, attribute.FormatErrorMessage(string.Empty), instance);
    }
}
```

In the small sample above I call the runner like so:

```
public class ColorScheme
{
     [Required]
     [StringLength(6)]
     public string Color1 {get; set; }

     public void Validate()
     {
         var errors = DataAnnotationsValidationRunner.GetErrors(this);
         if(errors.Any())
             throw new RulesException(errors);
     }
}
```

This is all overly simplistic but works.  A better solution when using MVC is the Mvc.DataAnnotions model binder which you can get from [codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471).  Its easy enough to build your own modelbinder from DefaultModelBinder, but no need to bother since its already been done.

Hope this helps.

PS.  Also found [this site](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html) which has some sample unit tests working with DataAnnotations.